# Angular not parsing data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Can someone explain why the below code is not working?
I am new to Angular and am trying a very basic example.
The HTML simply prints {{data1}} instead of "hi!".

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app='myApp'>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var module1=angular.module('myApp',[]);
        module1.controller('controller',function ($scope){
            $scope.data1='hi!';
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='controller'>
    <p>{{data1}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html ng-app='myApp'>
<html>
```

needs to be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myApp'>
```